# valgrinf error- how to interpretate it?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have the following error when using valgrind:

```
==3099== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3099==    at 0x40BA65D: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40BA98C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40C5A98: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40C5C13: std::ostream::operator<<(int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x80A5CC6: Ser::method() (in /home/user)
==3099==    by 0x80BCA61: bool Ser() (in /home/user)
==3099==    by 0x80958D1: Ser::Select() (in /home/user)
==3099==    by 0x804B85D: main (in /home/user)
==3099== 
==3099== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==3099==    at 0x40BA12E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40BA693: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40BA98C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40C5A98: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x40C5C13: std::ostream::operator<<(int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==3099==    by 0x80A5CC6: Ser::method() (in /home/user)
==3099==    by 0x80BCA61: bool Ser::Call() (in /home//user)
==3099==    by 0x80958D1: Ser::Select() (in /home/user)
==3099==    by 0x804B85D: main (in /home/user)
```

What does this mean?
Where is the error?

Comment: Have you at least try to read the message? Have you looked up the methods mentioned in the message?

Comment: yes i did. id on't see the error

Comment: why don't you post the refered code, then? I.e., the code inside `Ser::method()` and other relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you are working with some variables before they were initialized. Looks like you are printing uninitialized `int` value in `Ser::method()`. You should initialize it before printing.

Comment: @sunset: How are we supposed to know? Read the "error" message and try to understand it. Then post the relevant code portion, otherwise we simply can't tell if this is a big error or just something cosmetical

Comment: @sunset: Boo. Demands our time but does not post the solution. Maybe go for a paid forum then.

Comment: @phresnal: People don't respect something if they are given it for free. Want to set up a consultancy?

Comment: @john: True. And especially not if they can hide behind a keyboard.